# Filling out textbox after clicking on a checkbox with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, text, input, checkbox

I have the following text inputs for Name and Last Name in a form:

```
<label>First name: </label></td>
<input type="text" name="firstName">
<label>Last name: </label></td>
<input type="text" name="lastName"></td>
```

Then I have another text input for Credit Card holder followed by a checkbox:

```
<input type="text" size="20" id="nameOnCard" name="nameOnCard" data-stripe="name"/></td>
<input type="checkbox" id="sameNameOnCard">
```

I would like the #nameOnCard input to get filled up with the First Name and the Last Name whenever the user clicks on the checkbox.

I started with some script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sameNameOnCard").click(function(){
```

How should I retrieve the info from the Firts and Last Names and plug it into the nameOnCard box?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sameNameOnCard").on("click", function () {
        var firstName, lastName;
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            firstName = $('[name="firstName"]').val();
            lastName = $('[name="lastName"]').val();
            $("#nameOnCard").val(firstName + " " + lastName).prop("readonly", true);
        } else {
            $("#nameOnCard").val("").prop("readonly", false);
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/hF26S/1/

It will get the first and last name elements with the jQuery "attribute equals" selector (because the only way to get them is by `name` attribute), get their values with `.val()`, and then set the final textbox's value.

I added something a little extra, to set the "nameOnCard" element to be `readonly` when the checkbox is checked, so they can't type in it when it's checked.

If the checkbox is checked at the time of being clicked, it copies the first and last name. If the checkbox is unchecked, it sets the value to be empty.

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sameNameOnCard").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
        {
             $("#nameOnCard").val($("input:[name=firstName]").val() + " " + $("input:[name=lastName]").val());
        }
        else
        {
               $("#nameOnCard").val("");
        }
    });
```